# Find a subset from a set of integer whose sum is closest to a value

Tags: algorithm

As the title said, Find a subset from a set of integer whose sum is closest to a value.
The set is about 1000 items in it, the value is about 10 million, I have considered using the DP(Dynamic Programming) to solve this problem, just as the "Bin Packing Problem", But this method is not suitable, the set is too large and the value is too large.

What can i do, trying Heuristic Algorithm? But How and use Which?

Comment: Is there some reason that you are asking this question here, and not reading any of many, ***many*** articles on this topic available to you in 5 seconds through Google?

Comment: There's seemingly no answer within 5 seconds because the problem has no name. However, read [Wikipedia:SSP-Polynomial-Time-Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm) !

Comment: [A very similar problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Answer (score 0):

A heuristic algorithm:

Order set smallest to largest

1. Find largest value smaller than desired value (binary search)
2. Starting from smallest value, try values up to value found in step 1. If exact match you are done. Otherwise until sum would exceed target. Save this combination of values.
3. Repeat from 1. starting with next smaller value found in 1, to compose another sum. Repeat until out of values
4. When exhausted, pick sum closet to target.

Comment: Can you give some proof?

Comment: Nope. It's a heuristic.

Comment: Motivation? Why don't you try it. Do you have a counter example that shows the logic to be flawed?

Comment: would the downvoter please leave a comment (if it wasn't @justhalf)

Comment: sigh, that's supposed to be your job as answer-giver. Ok, can you please give more explanation what do you mean in your second step as "save this combination of values"?

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to understand your heuristic to find counter-example. Please help me =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient it would be, but you can try the MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Programming) approach.

LP Formulation:

```
Variables: Xi = 1 if element No. i is selected.
           Z1: Negative deviation from VALUE
           Z2: Positive deviation from VALUE

Minimize Objective function:
   Z1 + Z2      // Given the nature of problem, at most 1 among Z1 and Z2 shall be > 0.

Subject to constraint:
   summation(WiXi) + Z1 - Z2 = VALUE
   Xi = 0 or 1.
   Z1, Z2 >= 0
```

You can solve the above Integer Linear Programming using any solver package.

Comment: You can improve this post by explaining what is MILP and LP.